# Does a declined flag cause a 2 point loss?

Tags: support

Yesterday I got a declined flag about an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479824/codedom-dynamic-code-generation-detected-as-a-virus/30980027#30980027) 
After a short while 2 points where subtracted from my reputation.

Are these two events linked?

It happened before a couple of time that I lost 2 points but I imagined it was because an edited answer was deleted.

But even looking at my reputation history applying what is suggested in the possible duplicate question (showing up removed posts) I can see that I had two suggested edits removed on Apr 18 and Apr 25 but nothing yesterday.

Is there something else I'm missing?

Any thought about this is welcomed.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Casting flags does not impact on your rep.

Comment: Well, VLQ, Offensive and Spam flags can impact on the post owners rep.